# PyQt GUI change Button-text process time

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pyqt, sleep

I don't understand much about Gui action execution order etc., but my Problem is very simple:
I have a Code that looks like this:

```
button.setText('text')
do sth
time.sleep(1)
do sth else
```

Somehow the script always fails to set the text before the timeout, and therefore the timeout also breaks this action and the text appears only after the timeout. How can I tell this line of code to finish execution dispite the time.sleep()? Or do i have to introduce an if-statement, only to wait until the button has set its text (is there a better way)

Thanks

Comment: Exactly I can understand your question. Please pass the exact code, then i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI applications typically use some event loop, which is responsible for actually painting your widgets, etc.

You can not block this event loop with a sleep, or your application will stop responding.

Instead, in the case of Qt, use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to invoke whatever you want to do asynchronously.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, but still for the record: QTimer was the solution of course. I used QTimer.singleshot so solve my problem.
Thanks!